# Java: How to make seperate class communicate with MainController on thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have a simple synthesizer program using JavaFX. I am trying to create a new class called Metronome to interact with the MainController class. I need the Metronome to run on it's own thread but still be able to run methods from the MainController, specifically on each beat. For example, when the metronome is turned on, it needs to (on it's own thread) set the fill color of a shape and make a sound through a method in the MainController. It will continuously change the color(off and on) and make the sound on a delayed loop until a method from the MainController stops the loop. How can I have the Metronome class communicate with my MainController and back while having it run on it's own thread?

EDIT: So I basically need my run() method in the metronome class to be able to run methods in the MainController class.

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    public AudioMain audio = new AudioMain();
    @ FXML public AnchorPane mainPane;

    public boolean debugMessages = true;
    public boolean debugMessages2 = false;
    public boolean debugMessages3 = false;

    //public final int numKeys = 13;
    public int C4 = 60; //The midi pitch of C4
    public int octave = 4; //The default octave to be assigned

    public String synthType = "Saw";
    public SynthSet synth = new SynthSet(111, synthType); //Creates a new SynthSet of 13 SineWaves

    public double bpm = 120;
    public Metronome metronome = new Metronome(bpm); 

    ....some code later....

    public void toggleMetronome() {
        metronome.toggleMet();
    }

    public void lightOn() {
        metronomeLight.setFill(lightOnColor);
    }

    public void lightOff() {
        metronomeLight.setFill(lightOffColor);
    }
```

And then..

```
public class Metronome implements Runnable{

    public boolean metronomeOn = false;
    public boolean metronomeSound = true;
    public boolean metOutputMessages = true;
    public boolean tick8th = false;
    public double bpm = 20;
    public long msPerBeat = (long) (60000 / bpm); // Miliseconds per beat
    public int tickCount = 0;
    public long nano;

    public Metronome() {

    }

    public Metronome(double beat) {
        setTempo(beat);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Metronome met = new Metronome();
        met.metOn();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(msPerBeat);
        while (metronomeOn) {
            beat();
            delay(msPerBeat/2);
            if (tick8th) beat8th();
            delay(msPerBeat/2);
        }
    }

    public void metOn() {
        if (!metronomeOn) {
            outMessage("Starting metronome at " + bpm + " bpm");
            metronomeOn = true;
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }

    public void metOff() {
        if (metronomeOn) {
            outMessage("Stopping metronome");
            metronomeOn = false;
        }
    }
    public void toggleMet() {
        if (metronomeOn) {
            metOff();
        }else if (!metronomeOn)
            metOn();
    }

    public void beat() {
        tickCount++;
        outMessage("Beep " + tickCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would usually do this using a condition variable or an event. As it stands, your question is somewhat too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Could you please share a code snippet ? Your question is too general. It's really difficult to answer.

Comment: You might consider using a [Timeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/basics.htm#BEIIDFJC) to control the metronome rather than a separate thread.  You could use a [KeyValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyValue.html) in the Timeline and a change listener to perform operations as the value changes.

Comment: You can just pass a reference to the `MainController` to the `Metronome` (e.g. via the constructor). Then call the `MainController` methods from the `run()` method, wrapped in a `Platform.runLater()`. However, I agree with the previous comments that this is better implemented with a `Timeline`.

Comment: @jewelsea a Timeline might actually be a great way to handle this. I'm new to java so I still don't know about a lot of the classes available. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample of a [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) based Metronome with some visual controls and Metronome beat timing indicator.

Sorry its a bunch of code.  You can make it more concise by not having separate classes for each concept and just inlining everything, but I find defining separate objects better once things start to get a bit non-trivial (as in this case).

The Metronome class generates beats via an observable property and the other classes use listeners to react to the beats.

[image: be still my beating heart]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.effect.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MetroGnome extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Metronome metronome = new Metronome();
        TempoControl tempoControl = new TempoControl(metronome);
        BeatIndicator beatIndicator = new BeatIndicator(metronome);
        PlayControl playControl = new PlayControl(metronome);

        HBox layout = new HBox(10, playControl, tempoControl, beatIndicator);
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class PlayControl extends ToggleButton {
    public PlayControl(Metronome metronome) {
        super("Start");

        setOnAction(event -> {
            if (isSelected()) {
                metronome.start();
                setText("Stop");
            } else {
                metronome.stop();
                setText("Start");
            }
        });
    }
}

class TempoControl extends VBox {
    private static final int MIN_TEMPO = 20;
    private static final int MAX_TEMPO = 240;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEMPO = 120;

    private Slider tempoSlider = new Slider(MIN_TEMPO, MAX_TEMPO, DEFAULT_TEMPO);
    private Label tempoLabel = new Label(tempoSlider.getValue() + "");

    public TempoControl(Metronome metronome) {
        super(5);

        tempoLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f", tempoSlider.valueProperty()));
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        getChildren().setAll(tempoLabel, tempoSlider);

        metronome.setTempo(tempoSlider.getValue());
        metronome.tempoProperty().bind(tempoSlider.valueProperty());
    }

    public DoubleProperty valueProperty() {
        return tempoSlider.valueProperty();
    }
}

class BeatIndicator extends Circle {
    // Ting sound from: http://soundbible.com/1628-Ting.html
    private static final String TING_SOUND = "Ting-Popup_Pixels-349896185.wav";

    private static AudioClip ting = new AudioClip(
            BeatIndicator.class.getResource(TING_SOUND).toExternalForm()
    );

    public BeatIndicator(Metronome metronome) {
        super(10, Color.RED);
        ChangeListener<Beat> beatChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            ting.play();
            setFill(newValue.getTickTock() == 0 ? Color.GREEN : Color.ORANGE);
        };

        DropShadow dropShadow = new DropShadow(5, (Color) getFill());
        fillProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                dropShadow.setColor((Color) newValue)
        );

        Glow beatEffect = new Glow();
        beatEffect.setInput(dropShadow);

        metronome.isRunningProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                setFill(Color.GREEN);
                setEffect(beatEffect);
                metronome.beatProperty().addListener(beatChangeListener);
            } else {
                metronome.beatProperty().removeListener(beatChangeListener);
                setFill(Color.RED);
                setEffect(null);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Metronome {
    private final double DEFAULT_TEMPO = 60;
    private ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Beat> beat = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(null);

    private Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

    // tempo is measured in beats per minute.
    private DoubleProperty tempo = new SimpleDoubleProperty(DEFAULT_TEMPO);
    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper isRunning = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(false);

    private int tickTock = 0;

    public Metronome() {
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0), event -> {
                    beat.set(new Beat(tickTock, timeline.getCurrentTime()));
                    tickTock = (tickTock + 1) % 2;
                }),
                new KeyFrame(
                        Duration.seconds(1)
                )
        );

        tempo.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                timeline.setRate(newValue.doubleValue() / 60.0)
        );
        timeline.setRate(tempo.getValue() / 60.0);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    }

    public void start() {
        tickTock = 0;
        isRunning.set(true);
        timeline.playFromStart();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timeline.stop();
        isRunning.set(false);
    }

    public double getTempo() {
        return tempo.get();
    }

    public DoubleProperty tempoProperty() {
        return tempo;
    }

    public void setTempo(double tempo) {
        this.tempo.set(tempo);
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Beat> beatProperty() {
        return beat.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty isRunningProperty() {
        return isRunning.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}

class Beat {
    private final Duration currentTime;
    // tickTock varies switches from one to zero on alternate generated beats.
    private final int tickTock;

    public Beat(int tickTock, Duration currentTime) {
        this.currentTime = currentTime;
        this.tickTock = tickTock;
    }

    public int getTickTock() {
        return tickTock;
    }

    public Duration getCurrentTime() {
        return currentTime;
    }
}
```